# Default theme crashing application

Tags: android

How to use device default theme? If I use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
  </style>
</resources>
```

it is crashing application. [Exception](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/81c78c8ac637b3f05983)

Comment: post logcat exception...

Comment: Sorry for newbie question, but how to filter that exception? (using Android studio)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Thanks for the hint, added link to gist, had problems with text formatting here.

Comment: Have you read the stacktrace? What unclear is in `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.` then?

Comment: Yes I have red and question stays the same. How to make app with native look? Theme.AppCompat is not system native style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if the theming is the issue but to apply themes you will do the following..

add/change in styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>

        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>

        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>
    <style name="StyledDialog.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>

        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>

        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

create a folder in res called values-v21 and copy the styles.xml into now change there the code to something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">

        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>

        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>

        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>


    <style name="StyledDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>

        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryColorDark</item>

        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>

</resources>
```

In your manifest you will have to call the theme by

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Now your app will support the default theming of Lollipop and earlier versions of android.

Edit: Don't get confused by the "Dialog"-entries.. I just overwrite them to apply the theming to them with an other style..

Comment: Thank you for the help. It partly solved theme problem. Main problem probably is in my phone. On emulators there are no problems.

Comment: That's nice. Which phone are you using?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S2 with CyanogenMod

Comment: Are you sure that the Sammy drivers run correctly? Maybe kill KIES... Do you use an original USB cable? The ROM shouldn't be the problem... I got a S2 running CM11 (for testing), too..